# Check a checkbox by default using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have the fallowing HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-remember" data-theme="SingleLineCheckBox" checked/>
```

but the checkbox still is not defaultly checked. I also tried using:

```
$("#checkbox-remember").prop('checked', true);
```

But i cant get it to work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aNrpL/ your checkbox **is** checked by default, your HTML is fine. Did you uncheck it at some stage and press refresh? Certain browsers remember your form settings even if you refresh. Close the tab, clear cache, and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I did all that. but it is still not checked when i first open the page. maybe it's something to do with jQuery?

Comment: What browser are you using? Perhaps the `checked` attribute is causing issues in earlier versions of IE?

Comment: both are working here : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/x9dc7/ which browser are you using? third one using checked="checked"

Comment: I am using chrome, and the file is a JSP file.
when i view the source of the page, it seems like the "checked" attribute has vanished from the html...

Answer (score 3):

Make always sure that your **DOM is ready**!

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready shorthand

    $("#checkbox-remember").prop('checked', true);

    // other code here

});
```

otherwise if you're able to change your HTML you can add the `checked` property to your checkbox. i.e: `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

<sub>It's also a good habit to put all you `<script>` tags right before the `</body>` tag making sure that the parser first read all your document tree before loading scripts.</sub>

Comment: Good find, I always just *assume* people wrap their jQuery in doc ready.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-remember" data-theme="SingleLineCheckBox" checked="checked"/>
```

Comment: yup, checked="checked" will help IE

Comment: @user2951938 you have not give the name to that checkbox try by giving the name attribute also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checkbox-remember" data-theme="SingleLineCheckBox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

have you got try other methods to know if the checkbox is check ?

I Have tried with

```
$('#checkbox-remember').get(0).checked
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWNfv/)